# Send a JSON and a zip attachment in the same response with cherrypy

Tags: python, json, rest, attachment, cherrypy

I want to send in the same HTTP response (with cherrypy) both a JSON response and a zip attachment. Is it possible?

Right now my code is:

```
def GET(self, **params):
    result, data = getData(params)
    cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="resp.zip"'
    return data
```

with which I am able to download the attachment. How to also send the JSON message?

Comment: so you want to send in the same response 2 content types `json` and `zip`, right?

Comment: Exactly, JSON as a response and zip at the same type.. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think so, since it is 2 different `Content-Type` header values. I would do it like  @andrew-kloos mentioned. Return a `json` with a link to a `zip` file inside.

Answer (score 0):

Ok you'll need to do something like this...

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'your-url-that-gives-zip-file.html',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(response){
        if(response.zip) {
            location.href = "GetZip?=zip" + response.zip;
        }
    }
});
```

Your cherrypy handler:

```
@cherrypy.expose 
def GetZip(self, zip=""):
    return """
    <!-- Get your zip file code with and combine with http://youradress.com -->
    <a href='http://youraddress.com/downloads/' + zip
    """
```

Hope this helps!